# Active class to clicked tab

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm learning `angularJs`, so I'm new to that & trying to add `active class` on recently clicked tab. Here I have four tabs (`insert, view, update & delete`). My desired is to add active class to `insert` tab when clicked on this tab & to view tab when clicked & so on. I have tried this but failed to do the job. My code adding `active` class to all tabs automatically. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Sorry for my poor English!

```css
body{
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-content{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-content button{
    background-color: dimgrey;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid dimgrey;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
}

.menu-content button:hover{
    color: gold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.crud{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.active{
    color: gold !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="menu-content">
        <button ng-click="activeClass('insert')" ng-class="{active: true}">Insert</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('view')" ng-class="{active: true}">View</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('update')" ng-class="{active: true}">Update</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('delete')" ng-class="{active: true}">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.insert">Insert</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.view">View</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.update">Update</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.delete">Delete</div>
</div>

<script>
    (function(){
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[ ]);
        app.controller('myController', function($scope){
            $scope.menu = {};
            $scope.menu.insert = true;
            $scope.menu.view = false;
            $scope.menu.update = false;
            $scope.menu.delete = false;

            $scope.activeClass = function(tab){
                $scope.menu.insert = false;
                $scope.menu.view = false;
                $scope.menu.update = false;
                $scope.menu.delete = false;
                if(tab == 'insert') $scope.menu.insert = true;
                else if(tab == 'view') $scope.menu.view = true;
                else if(tab == 'update') $scope.menu.update = true;
                else $scope.menu.delete = true;
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be `ng-class="{ active: menu.insert }"`, etc... here's your revised snippet:

```css
body{
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-content{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-content button{
    background-color: dimgrey;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid dimgrey;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
}

.menu-content button:hover{
    color: gold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.crud{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.active{
    color: gold !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="menu-content">
        <button ng-click="activeClass('insert')" ng-class="{active: menu.insert}">Insert</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('view')" ng-class="{active: menu.view}">View</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('update')" ng-class="{active: menu.update}">Update</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('delete')" ng-class="{active: menu.delete}">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.insert">Insert</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.view">View</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.update">Update</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.delete">Delete</div>
</div>

<script>
    (function(){
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[ ]);
        app.controller('myController', function($scope){
            $scope.menu = {};
            $scope.menu.insert = true;
            $scope.menu.view = false;
            $scope.menu.update = false;
            $scope.menu.delete = false;

            $scope.activeClass = function(tab){
                $scope.menu.insert = false;
                $scope.menu.view = false;
                $scope.menu.update = false;
                $scope.menu.delete = false;
                if(tab == 'insert') $scope.menu.insert = true;
                else if(tab == 'view') $scope.menu.view = true;
                else if(tab == 'update') $scope.menu.update = true;
                else $scope.menu.delete = true;
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You suggest me what I already done. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you every one, finally solved my problem. I mistook in my binding expression to `ng-class`. I solved this `ng-class="{active: menu.insert}"`. Now i understand how to use `ng-class` properly. I need need only make it `true` when it is clicked & other tab expression should be `false`. Here what I used to solve.

```css
body{
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-content{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-content button{
    background-color: dimgrey;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid dimgrey;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
}

.menu-content button:hover{
    color: gold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.crud{
    padding: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.active{
    color: gold !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="menu-content">
        <button ng-click="activeClass('insert')" ng-class="{active: menu.insert}">Insert</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('view')" ng-class="{active: menu.view}">View</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('update')" ng-class="{active: menu.update}">Update</button>
        <button ng-click="activeClass('delete')" ng-class="{active: menu.delete}">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.insert">Insert</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.view">View</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.update">Update</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.delete">Delete</div>
</div>

<script>
    (function(){
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[ ]);
        app.controller('myController', function($scope){
            $scope.menu = {};
            $scope.menu.insert = true;
            $scope.menu.view = false;
            $scope.menu.update = false;
            $scope.menu.delete = false;

            $scope.activeClass = function(tab){
                $scope.menu.insert = false;
                $scope.menu.view = false;
                $scope.menu.update = false;
                $scope.menu.delete = false;
                if(tab == 'insert') $scope.menu.insert = true;
                else if(tab == 'view') $scope.menu.view = true;
                else if(tab == 'update') $scope.menu.update = true;
                else $scope.menu.delete = true;
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

In my `ng-class` what I done is

```
<div class="menu-content">
    <button ng-click="activeClass('insert')" ng-class="{active: menu.insert}">Insert</button>
    <button ng-click="activeClass('view')" ng-class="{active: menu.view}">View</button>
    <button ng-click="activeClass('update')" ng-class="{active: menu.update}">Update</button>
    <button ng-click="activeClass('delete')" ng-class="{active: menu.delete}">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Thanks all again :)

Comment: rather than with 4 bools you can do it with single string variable, which should hold the value of clicked variable, this solution will be easily extendible even if you add 1 more tab in future

Comment: Yes, but I already used these four bool for showing or hide the contents. By those variable I can do the job, so I do not like to add another variable.

Comment: i meant you can replace all 4 variables by single variable, not adding a variable as such

Comment: Could you plz explain, I will be grateful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

since putting code in comments wont make it clear, hence putting it as an answer what I wanted to tell in comments.

```
    <div class="menu-content">
        <button ng-click="menu.selected = 'insert'" ng-class="{active: menu.selected == 'insert'}">Insert</button>
        <button ng-click="menu.selected = 'view'" ng-class="{active: menu.selected == 'view'}">View</button>
        <button ng-click="menu.selected = 'update'" ng-class="{active: menu.selected == 'update'}">Update</button>
        <button ng-click="menu.selected = 'delete'" ng-class="{active: menu.selected == 'delete'}">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.selected == 'insert'">Insert</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.selected == 'view'">View</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.selected == 'update'">Update</div>
    <div class="crud" ng-show="menu.selected == 'delete'">Delete</div>
```

note : i havent tested the code, but should be enough to give you the concept

this will remove extra bool variables and works as sort of enum.

so extending it would be really easy than the bool approach